# Cannot seem to load polyfill for temporal

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've been trying to load a Temporal and am getting the below error on load when using the polyfill from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/temporal-polyfill).

```
WARNING: Failed to load script at /resource/1654451285000/temporal: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Temporal') [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Temporal')]
```

Here below is my code stripped down can you see anything obvious.

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import TemporalStatic from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/temporal';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TZDateTime extends LightningElement {

    temporalloaded = false;

    connectedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, TemporalStatic)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Loaded Temporal');
            this.temporalloaded = true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Failed Temporal');
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    handleDateTimeChange(event) {
        this.datetime = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

Temporal is just a static resource with the javascript file uploaded to it as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the WARNING, the browser tries to read the property "Temporal" of an undefined object. Looking at the Temporal Javascript lib in its current version 0.0.7 and searching for "Temporal", at its very end one can read

> globalThis.Temporal

Ouch! [globalThis is not supported by LockerService](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer).

Consider using Lightning Web Security. Tick the respective box under Setup/Security/Session Settings (don't forget to empty your browser cache) and reload.